# Alterar style de uma div

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho uma div que fica escondida na tela:

```
 <div id="selectCity" name="selectCity" 
    class="form-group col-md-12" style="display: none;" >

    <label for="cities">Para os usuários da cidade:</label>
    <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('cities')); ?>

 </div>
```

Ao trocar a seleção do radio group ela deve ficar visível. Para isso uso este código:

```
function handleClick(myRadio) {
   if (myRadio.value.localeCompare("selecteduser") === 0) { 
       document.getElementsById("selectCity").style.display = "block";
   } else {
       document.getElementsById("selectCity").style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

handlerClick é chamado, a verificação é feita sem maiores problemas. O problema é o style da div não é alterado.

Alguem consegue me dizer o porque?

Comment: Uma pergunta @franM, você não pode usar jQuery? Acho que fica bem mais fácil trabalhar.

Comment: Pode ser jQuery

Comment: Coloquei na resposta havia entendido errado mas já encontrei um problema

Comment: Boa tarde, não use tags irrelevantes pra pergunta, use tags sobre o problema e não sobre o projeto. Tenho certeza que você vai levar o meu comentário como uma critica construtiva.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Segue abaixo um exemplo, e quando é id não se usa getElementsById usa o getElementById

```
function handleClick(myRadio) {
   if (myRadio.value.localeCompare("selecteduser") === 0) { 
       document.getElementById("selectCity").style.display = "block";
   } else {
       document.getElementById("selectCity").style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando jQuery

> No rádio que vai executar a ação de mostrar

```
$("#idDoRadio").on("click", function(){
   $("#idDaDiv").show();
});
```

> E no radio que vai realizar a ação de ocultar

```
$("#idDoRadio").on("click", function(){
   $("#idDaDiv").hide();
});
```